# How can I create a single ISO or IMG file from an SD card?

Tags: windows, backup, iso-image, sd-card

I have an SD card that contains 2 volumes (H and I).  I have found programs where I can turn Drive H and I into an ISO or IMG seperately.  But I want a program that will take the entire card and turn it into an IMG or ISO file with all the volume info.  I have done this with hard drives using the program reflect, but reflect doesn't see the SD card.  IMGBURN will allow me to do either H or I independantly...

Does anyone know what my options are?  I've Tried easeus disk copy, easeus backup, winimage, win32diskimager, RMPprep, and USB image tool...

Answer (score 10):

You can use [ImageUSB](https://www.osforensics.com/tools/write-usb-images.html)... this software clones in a single .bin image all the content of your sd card, even if you have multiple partitions.

[ImageUSB screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CB71i.png)

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Might be okay for USB flash drives but I'm not sure about SD Cards.  Doesn't see the SD Card slot on my Lenovo laptop, anyway.

Comment: This does not work for SD card readers which are internally connected via PCIe. Don't waste your time if you're on a fairly modern laptop.

Answer (score 7):

To create image of the **whole card** (not just one Windows-visible partition), you can use **dd for Windows** (http://www.chrysocome.net/dd).

Run CMD as Administrator:

```
dd --list
```

Check which device is your SD card. In my case it was: `\\?\Device\Harddisk1\Partition0`. `Partition0` refers to the whole disk, `Partition1` to the first partition, etc.

Copy whole SD card to an image file:

```
dd if=\\?\Device\Harddisk1\Partition0 of=my.img bs=1M --progress
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me -- I was able to img a RaspberryPi card w/ 2 parts from within Windows. dd for Windows is available here: http://www.chrysocome.net/download Version 0.6Beta3 appears to be the latest version still.

Comment: there's now ddrelease64.exe available

Answer (score 4):

Since you are in windows you can simply use the same program you mentioned 'win32diskimager'.  Press the folder icon and select the location and file name you want to create. (sdcard.img) and write. Tool will clone the entire SD card as it is. If you can use Linux you can easily do that using dd command like this

```
dd if=/dev/sdc/ of=/home/sdcard.img
```

Replace the sdc and sdcard.img with appropriate names

If you worrying finding machine with Linux you can simply enable Windows subsystems for Linux (WSL) which gives you full featured Linux terminal on your windows

Comment: I tried that, but under device I can pick Drive H or drive I.  But not the entire card.  Both Drives H and I are on that one card, so I want both to be in the image as is.  Basically its a raspberry PI, and I want to clone it, so if the card dies, I just apply the img to a new.  H is the boot partition, I is the file structure.

Comment: Macrium Reflect (free) allows selecting whole drives including the boot sector or only some of its partitions (what you call "drive H" and "drive I" are actually partitions in the same drive).

Comment: yep, reflect doesn't work with flash media.  I did try AEOMI and it seemed to do it.  it created it as a .adi file.  I'll have to test.

Comment: Windows Subsystem doesn't allow to get info about disks (`lsblk` failed, some disks are not mounted under `/mnt`).